# Simplify fraction with a $\pm$ value numerator

Tags: fractions

What are the steps to simplify by $2$ as shown? I am not clear on how this is does while still maintaining the $\pm$.

$$\frac{6\pm2\sqrt{6}}{-6}$$

To:

$$\frac{3\pm\sqrt{6}}{-3}$$

[Equation step 6 to 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93G1G.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is equivalent to $$\frac{2(3\pm\sqrt{6})}{-6}=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{6}}{-3}$$

Comment: Thank you - would you recommend rewording of the title?

Answer (score 0):

They simply take 2 common from numerator. And divide numerator and denominator by 2.

$2\left[\frac{3\pm\sqrt{6}}{-6}\right]$

$\frac{3\pm\sqrt{6}}{-3}$

If you still confused.

First write different values.

$\frac{6 +2\sqrt{6}}{-6}, \frac{6 - \sqrt{6}}{-6}$

Now simplify them individually.